# Getting list of heavy aggregates

Tags: rest, repository, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

Suppose we have such an aggregate in our domain that it is stored in table hierarchy three levels deep. Let's denote domain objects as `Order`-`OrderItems`-`ItemAttributes`.
Let's also assume that we use the Repository pattern on our Data layer.

Repository contains method `GetAll` that returns the listing of `Orders`.

We follow REST on our service layer, hence, we use

- `GET /orders` to get the listing
- `GET /orders/{Id}` to get the concrete `Order`

The listing contains only the basic fields of each `Order` without details, however, the query by id returns bigger object.

As materialization of one `Order` is expensive operation, we don't like the fact that we get full aggregates just to send a couple of fields to a client. On the other hand, we try follow the reasonable rule that repository must return only fully initialized aggregates.

How could we solve this difficulty?

Comment: One word: CQRS http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/05/04/CQRS-Explained.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from CQRS as suggested by others, would a simple [Lazy loading](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/lazy-loading-eager-loading.aspx) be a good solution to this problem? Order items will not be loaded if they are not accessed. Or a dedicated OrderSummary/OrderStatus domain object if you can not use lazy loading?

Also it is always worth reconsidering whether a heavy aggregate is really needed. There may simply be no domain rules that call for it. Life cycle for example is a well known 'wrong reason' for having heavy aggregates (like Group->User, or Product->BacklogItem). Highly recommended read on this subject: [Aggregate design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/).

Comment: the problem with lazy loading is that I've used Order-OrderItems for simplification :-) There's actually a lot of event-driven logic within that aggregate, that examines the whole hierarchy. Thanks for the link, I'll definitely try to read what you've suggested.